# Running on port 80 after git deployment and ignored local.js

Tags: git, sails.js

The variable process.env.PORT is set in local.js, and to 1337 by default.

But local.js is included in .gitignore for good reasons.

So, how are people getting their git deployed apps running on :80?

What about other configurations that are in local.js, like process.env.NODE_ENV='production' ?

Comment: I hadn't been able to get my app running on heroku to test this, but now have. Seems to pick up port :80 automagically - probably has process.env.PORT set to 80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Sails v0.10-rc7, you can store per-environment configuration files in the `config/env` directory.  So, you could create a file `config/env/production.js`, with:

```
port: 80
```

among other things, and whenever the app is run in that environment, those settings will be used.

Prior to v0.10-rc7, the options were to a) place a `config/local.js` file on the server, or b) use environment variables (like the `PORT` environment var you mentioned) to override the default config.